# There is seemingly no way to get a Sketchup model to work properly in Blender. Pls help

Tags: export, import

I'm very new to blender, I've had a very frustrating experience trying to get something from Sketchup Make to Blender to Unreal Engine, with seemingly no way to do it. 
Sketchup Make only allows me to export as a .dae file or a .kmz file.

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/za2xA.jpg
Here, I tried to import the .dae file.

On the right, you can see that the material still 'exists', as I can click on each individual polygon on the right and have it's assigned texture be recognised.

Unfortunately, for some reason, these don't appear on the actual model. Exporting a model like this to an FBX or OBJ to use in Unreal means I end up with a useless model which is unable to be correctly textured. (Also, every single polygon in the model is a separate object for some reason. Why is that? It means dealing with it in Unreal is a complete nightmare.)

I've read online that you have to assign each texture to each face. Well, for me, that will take literal hours. So I just can't afford to do that.

I also tried importing .skp files straight into blender with a plugin.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLa5P.jpg
When I do that, all the textures become solid colours in blender (yes, I've tried 'Rendered' mode and along with rendering it and everything) and the UV maps are still completely screwed in Unreal, with the maps being so small that any texture just becomes solid colour.

All I want is for a Sketchup model, which I've spent heaps of time making exactly the way want, to be imported into Blender. Or even better, straight into Unreal.

Does anyone have alternatives? Can someone please please help me out? I can't find a single tutorial or forum post that actually works. I run into some sort of different problem every single time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: One shouldn't add texture to each face of the mesh and it doesn't mean the model can't have textures if imported material doesn't show them; probably materail is set up wrongly upon import.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that it works with Blender render, but not cycles render. Once in blender render mode (not cycles) change your view to *Material* rather than shaded or textured. You'll see your sketchup model as it appears in sketchup, with slightly better rendering. Rendering from here doesn't work well. 
Cheers